# Prestashop services in hookDisplayFooterProduct

Tags: service, module, prestashop, hook

I have problems with module working and hope You can help me:

In hook displayFooterProduct ( main module file ) i have links to services like this:

```
$variable = $this->get('prestashop.module.[module_name].[repository_name]')->foo($this->service_token, $params['id_product']);
```

Everyting works fine if debug mode is ON, but if I turn it OFF I get nothing ( hook is empty ).

Even changing the service name to a random one does not cause in errors.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after turning OFF the debug mode?

Comment: Yes, several times - programmatically and manualy from folder. I checked the module online and locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution/cause of the problems.
Manually clearing the cache works, but I changed arguments line first in **services.yml** from:

```
arguments: ['@doctrine.dbal.default_connection', '%database_prefix%', 'module_name', '1.0.0']
```

to:

```
arguments: 
  -  '@doctrine.dbal.default_connection'
  -  '%database_prefix%'
  -  'module_name'
  -  '1.0.0'
```

And then cleared cache.
Maybe someone will find this solution useful.